# How to prevent type alias preservation?

Tags: typescript

In version 4.2, TypeScript [improved type alias preservation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#smarter-type-alias-preservation). This means that if you hover over a variable that was declared using a type alias, IDEs will show you the friendly name of that type alias rather than the raw structure of the type.

There are, however, cases where this isn't desirable. Consider the following example:

```
interface Animal {
  name: string;
  speed: number;
  legCount: number;
}

let foo: Omit<Animal, 'legCount' | 'speed'>;
```

This uses the [utility type `Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to create a new type that is a subset of `Animal`. Hovering over the variable `foo` shows this tooltip:

[image: let foo: Omit<Animal, "legCount" | "speed">]

This tells me how the type was constructed, but it doesn't tell me anything about the type itself:

- It doesn't tell me what properties it has (`name`).
- It doesn't tell me the types of those properties (`string`).
- It doesn't tell me how to create a value matching this type.

In this case, I'd much prefer to see something like `let foo: { name: string }`.

So my question is: *How can I tell TypeScript to reduce an aliased type to its mere structure, discarding the name of the type alias used?*

The strange thing is that this type alias preservation doesn't always happen:

```
let test: Uppercase<'foo'>;
```

Hovering over `test` in this example shows me `let test: "FOO"`, *not* `let test: Capitalize<'foo'>`. So there seems to be some kind of heuristic at work that decides whether to preserve the type alias or not. I'd just like a way to control this choice myself.

Comment: For things like this I usually write a utility type called `Expand<T>` which maps over the properties of `T` explicitly.  For your code it looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m35x3w).  It's not perfect, but since TypeScript doesn't give us an explicit handle to control how a type is displayed, it's the best I can do.  See the answer to the linked question for details.